# Is there a way to watch WPF Routed Events?

Tags: wpf, debugging, routed-events

I was wondering if there's a way to watch all RoutedEvents that are raised in a WPF application. A way to write some info about the events fired to the console would be prefect to see what's going on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, but it requires some reflection. You're better off using a tool like [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) that already does the hard lifting for you.

In the tab **Events** you can see list of events, and the element that handled it.

Answer (score 22):

I've found another way:

I've added this to the loaded handler of my UserControl.

```
var events = EventManager.GetRoutedEvents();
foreach (var routedEvent in events)
{
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(myUserControl), 
                                      routedEvent, 
                                      new RoutedEventHandler(handler));
}
```

and this is the handler method:

```
internal static void handler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RoutedEvent.ToString() != "CommandManager.PreviewCanExecute" &&
            e.RoutedEvent.ToString() != "CommandManager.CanExecute")
        Console.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource+"=>"+e.RoutedEvent);
}
```

The *CanExecute* events are a bit too much in my case. If you would like to see these too, just remove the *if* statement.

Comment: Brilliant! It is always great if you can use existing utilities of the framework, instead of using third-party tools